# selectizeInput paramter 'multiple' unchangeable when updated server-side

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `selectizeInput` (with parameter `multiple = FALSE`) in a shiny app. I´m not able to change the multiple-parameter afterwards by using the server-side `updateSelectizeInput()` and setting the option there.

Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "name",
    label = "Select Name:",
    choices = NULL
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updateSelectizeInput(
    inputId = "name",
    choices = c("Markus", "Lisa", "Peter"),
    options = list(maxItems = 10),
    server = TRUE # set consciously, I have a big list to handle
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I don´t set the `server` parameter to TRUE, everything works just fine. Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Perhaps you should restart your RStudio or Laptop.

Comment: Are you able to select multiple items in the app @YBS? That's my goal. I´m executing code on RStudio Workstation and get the bug for shiny version 1.6.0 & 1.7.0 in a clean workspace. Also tried different R-Versions without success.

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple items, you can set `multiple=TRUE` in the `selectizeInput` as shown below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "name",
    label = "Select Name:",
    choices = NULL, multiple=T
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  updateSelectizeInput(
    inputId = "name",
    choices = c("Markus", "Lisa", "Peter"),
    options = list(maxItems = 10),
    server = TRUE # set consciously, I have a big list to handle
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I know this option can be set in the ui and it works well. My pain point is, that I want to start with an single select dropdown and change it from the server while the app is running as I dont know which to use beforehand.

Comment: As `choices=NULL` in the `ui`, the choices are really coming from the server side via `updateSelectizeInput()`.